# Strongswan ipsec tunneling between two VMs

Tags: vpn, tunnel, ipsec, strongswan

I am very new to `VPN` and `IPsec` tunneling. I have two `VMs` between them I need to establish `IPsec` tunnel by using `pre-defined PSK` key or provided certificate `.pem`.
I have installed `strongswan-5.9.6-1.el8.x86_64` on both `VMs`.
When I check the `strongswan` documentation it says about `swanctl` and `ipsec` command line interface. My confusion is which command line tool I can use with `strongswan-5.9.6-1.el8.x86_64`?

Can you please give me an example how to configure `*.conf` (`ipsec.conf` or `swanctl.conf`) for establishing tunnel between two VM

What is `strongswan.conf` used for. Do I need to make the changes in this file also? what changes? for `IPsec` tunneling.

Comment: You may want to visit the site of the maintainer: https://www.strongswan.org/ . There you can find a bunch of examples on how to set up StrongSwan (for both ipsec and swanctl) that you can modify to suit your needs. You should also feel free to experiment with them.

Answer (score 0):

The point is, you make the decision which type of interface (`ipsec` or `strongswan`) you are going to use when installing it (Debian, for example, offers both), then adjust */etc/ipsec.conf* or */etc/swanctl/swanctl.conf* depending on the controller that you have chosen (*strongswan-starter* or *strongswan-swanctl*).

As far as */etc/strongswan.conf* is concerned, that is used for general settings (logging, authentication methods, etc.) concerning StrongSwan, but connection and authentication specifics are made in the appropriate config files (*/etc/ipsec.conf* for *strongswan-starter* or */etc/swanctl/swanctl.conf* for *strongswan-swanctl*).

Also note that you cannot mix both control methods - if you have chosen one particular method on a particular host, stick to it. If you want to switch methods, you need to transform your settings from one format to the other and also install the appropriate package.

Comment: Thank you for your response. If I go with `strongswan-swanctl` controller which package I need to install. How can I start the strongswan (what is the command)?

Comment: @ppb You need to install both *strongswan* and *strongswan-swanctl* (don't be surprised that *strongswan-starter* is automatically installed along with *strongswan*). If you want to control StrongSwan manually, it's *swanctl*, and if you want to bring it up during boot, you need to issue `systemctl enable strongswan-swanctl.service`, and if you want to bring it up as a service, you'd use `systemctl start strongswan-swanctl.service`.